# Trying to understand this line of Java, as C# code

Tags: c#, java, .net, regex

See this java code :-

`s = s.replaceAll( "\\\\", "\\\\\\\\" ).replaceAll( "\\$", "\\\\\\$" );`

I sorta don't understand it. It's a regex replace all.

I've tried the following C# code...

```
text = text.RegexReplace("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
text = text.RegexReplace("\\$", "\\\\\\$");
```

But if i have the following unit test :-

`} ul[id$=foo] label:hover {`

The java code returns: `} ul[id\$=foo] label:hover {`

My c# code returns: `} ul[id\\\$=foo] label:hover {`

So i'm not sure I understand why my c# code is putting more `\`'s in, mainly with regards to how these control characters are being represented.. ??

---

#### Update:

So, when i use XXX's idea of just using `text.Replace(..)`, this works.
eg.

```
text = text.Replace("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
text = text.Replace("\\$", "\\\\\\$");
```

But I was hoping to stick with RegEx... to try and keep it as close to the java code as possible.

The extension method being used is...

```
public static string RegexReplace(this string input, 
    string pattern, 
    string replacement)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
}
```

hmm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java needs all `$` signs escaped in its replace string - `"\\\\\\$"` means `\\` and `\$`. Without it it throws an error: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplace.html (look for "$ (unescaped dollar as literal text)").

Remember `$1`, `$0` etc are replaced the text with captured groups, so there are a part of the syntax on the second argument to `replaceAll`. `C#` has a slightly different syntax, and doesn't require the extra slash, which it takes literally.

You could write:

```
text = text.RegexReplace(@"\\", @"\\");
text = text.RegexReplace(@"\$", @"\$");
```

Or,

```
text = text.RegexReplace(@"[$\\]", @"\$&");
```

Comment: So both Java and C# need a slash to be escaped. But in Java, they also need $ to be escaped?

Comment: but @Gabe and @CodeCanvas suggest it's not a regex replacement going on?

Comment: They are both exactly correct - if this isn't a simplified version, you don't need a rexeg here. Also, there is no `String.RegexReplace` method in C#, unless you're using an extension method.

Comment: @Kobi - yeah, you're right. I just noticed it is an extension method that does Regex.Replace(..).

Comment: @Kobi - i've updated the OT with some updated info. It's still not getting the expected output, when using your suggestion. hmmmm...

Comment: @Pure.Krome - If Gabe's code is working for you you should prefer it. The Java code is using a regex because it doesn't expose a normal string replacing method - you shouldn't write weird C# code because of that Java oddity. `:)`

Comment: In JAVA you can use you own string with replace that takes REGEX as an argument **str.replce("[A-Z]","")** in C# you need to use Regex.Replace

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the equivalent of this C# code:

```
text = text.Replace(@"\", @"\\"); 
text = text.Replace("$", @"\$");
```

The `@` indicates a verbatim string in C#, meaning that the backslashes in strings don't have to be escaped with more backslashes. In other words, the code replaces a single backslash with a double backslash and then replaces a dollarsign with a backslash followed by a dollarsign.

If you were to use the regex function, it would be something like this:

```
text = text.RegexReplace(@"\\", @"\\"); 
text = text.RegexReplace(@"\$", @"\$$");
```

Note that in the regex pattern (the first parameter), backslashes are special, while in the replacement (the second parameter) it is the dollarsigns that are special.

Comment: so you're saying that Java:`"\\\\", "\\\\\\\\"` is single backslash getting replaced to a double backslash? i thought that's two blackslashes, to 4. ??

Comment: Pure.Krome: The Java `replaceAll` function does a regex replace. Half the backslashes are removed by the Java compiler, then half of the remaining ones are removed by the regex compiler. What's left is the literal.

Comment: @Pure.Krome - no, it's a single backslash. You escape twice: once for the string (so the compiler sees `\\`), and again for regex engine - two backslashes in a string is a single backslash match.

Comment: "The @ indicates a literal string in C#..." - the @"" is a _verbatim_ string literal, "" is a string literal.

Answer (score -1):

The code quotes the backslashes and '$' characters in the original string.

Comment: hi dude .. i sorta don't understand your answer. Which code? And i'm doing what?

Comment: basically it replaces a single backslash with 2 backslashes, and replaces '$' with '\$'. It is done for the same reason why we write `printf("\\");` to get the output `\` -- in this example, `\` is a special character to `printf`, and the way to tell `printf` that you want a literal `\` (instead of the special meaning) is to quote it (and the quoting character is `\`, hence `\\`).

Answer (score -1):

Java regex parsing: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx

I *think* that in Java, you have to escape the \ character by using \, but in C#, you don't.  Try taking out half of the \ in your C# version.

Comment: \ needs to be escaped in C# string literals, but not in verbatim sring literals (i.e. string foo = @"\";)